# Pycharm running wrong version

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to run `pip install praw` for a project but I get the following error

```
praw requires Python '>3.5.3' but the running Python is 2.7.15
```

I can't find anything that indicates Python 2.7 is running on my system.

```
python --version
```

shows `Python 3.8.0`

if I check the preferences in PyCharm the interpreter listed is Python 3.8 at usr/local/bin/python3.8

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: You may use `where <command>` command to see where the executable of the command location. https://superuser.com/questions/49104/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-an-executable-in-windows

Comment: When `pip install pkg_name` is being used this should occur inside a venv. You could create a venv by running `python3 -m venv .venv && source .venv/src/bin/activate` then installing whatever packages you need inside the venv, and also activate the venv for pycharm too. Also most likely the interpreter in PyCharm being listed is wrong, can you show us a screenshot pls?

Comment: @Mark I was previously using a venv and this worked fine for `pip install praw` however I was having difficulty getting the package for psycopg2 to properly zip for my lambda.

Comment: @PepeElMago33 running `where python` gives an error `where: command not found`

Comment: He means `which python`. Also have you tried installing via pip3 install praw? Since I am confused if you are running these commands inside a venv or not??

Comment: You can also install packages in PyCharm's `Interpreter Settings`, just click the `+` button, then type `praw` and click `Install Package`. This way is guaranteed to install in your project's virtual environment.